# Android studio is not opening when clicking the android studio icon on window10

Tags: android, android-studio-2.2

latest Android studio i.e 2.2  was working fine on window 10 until yesterday. But suddenly it crashed. When i am trying to open the android studio again nothing is happening i.e neither any error nor the studio window.

I tried reinstalling two times but no success.

Attached is my environment variable settings snap.

Any pointer/help is appreciated..[environment variable settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4AZj.png)

Comment: Are you plugged mobile on USB when open android studio. If yes please remove it.

Comment: No mobile is not plugged...

Comment: isit show in the task manager?

Comment: no it is not showing in task manager also

Comment: run as administrator and see task manager if EXE file of android studio is run or not.

Comment: Tried that also but no luck..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this, go to "C:\Users\" and there you will have to do the following
 1. delete ".AndroidStudio2.2" folder
 2. if this does not works then delete all ".AndroidStudiox.x" folders
 3. if this also does not works then remove ".android" and ".gradle" folders
 4. and if these fails too, try reinstalling Android Studio after deleting those folders

Answer (score 1):

C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_11\bin; you just set the environmental path with your JDK bin folder whatever place you install your JDK. give full path with bin folder.  like given example